# Cypher - ID of node in WHERE clause - no variable in match clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's consider the following query:

```
MATCH (a), (b) WHERE NOT (b)-[:X]->(a) AND id(b) = 1
```

In other words, is it possible to express it in following manner:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE NOT (node with id=1)-[:X]->(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to define a property match inline in a pattern, you cannot do this with the actual graph id.

It's also important to remember that the difference between inlining a property in a pattern is just syntactical sugar, and will be interpreted by the compiler into the exact same thing as if you had defined the predicate in the WHERE clause.